# iOS device only "Unhandled Promise Rejection: OperationError: Failed to apply the received candidate" in webrtc video streaming application

Tags: ios, web-applications, safari, webrtc, wowza

I am getting ""Unhandled Promise Rejection: OperationError: Failed to apply the received candidate in webrtc video streaming application while its publishing the video specially from iOS device.

Behavior is random, some time its start publishing at first time but some time after 2-3 refresh and when its not publishing then i am getting above exception in the console log of browser.

A quick help is highly appropriated.

[image: Screen shot of debugging window of safari browser using chrome inspect device]

Comment: Hello! Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes, I have fixed this. had to re-trigger the connection activity as work around. share your code to suggest you further.